# In a UML use case diagram, can a user be represented by more than one actor?

Tags: use-case

In a nutshell, I'm wanting to know if a user within a system could be represented by more than one actor.

To give some background, I'm attempting to create a use case diagram for a technology business whereby the staffing is quite complex. The majority of the actions within the use case will be based on whether that staff is assigned to deal with domestic/corporate customers (or both,) has access to hardware/software products (or both,) and is able to deal with sales/leasing (or both.) For instance, corporate leasing hardware staff need access to corporate customers, leasing information and hardware products.

I'm wanting to use inheritance to make the use case look cleaner, and if I have an actor for every job role I'll have 18 of them. Therefore, I'm hoping that I can separate these by corporate/domestic and all of these other factors, but then to perform some actions multiple actors would need to be checked. For example, when attempting to add a sale of hardware products for corporate customers, the use case would need to demonstrate that the user must have access to sales, hardware products and corporate customers via the actors.

I'm racking my brain trying to think of the best way to do this, but nothing seems to be ideal. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hoping that I can separate these by corporate/domestic and all of these other factors, but then to perform some actions multiple actors would need to be checked.

Yes! you need to separate the use cases in a suitable way. Then **use all the users relevant to that use case** as actors. You can draw one actor in any number of use cases.

Ex:

[image: use case diagram]